# Overlaying Firefox's new Addon Manager

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a conditional overlay for firefox's new addon manager in minefield 3.7 (aka firefox 3.7)

I'm trying the following:

```
overlay    chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/addons.xul application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} appversion<3.7
overlay    chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/addonstab.xul application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} appversion>=3.7
```

And this works for firefox 3.6, but it does not work minefield.. y?

**Edit:**
even the following doesn't appear to work in minefield, but does in FF 3.6 (I just made the overlay add a blank css file, an dI can find the css file included in FF 3.6 but not Minefield):

```
overlay    chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/addonstab.xul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565610).

Answer (score 1):

3.7a5pre is less than 3.7, so it will not apply.  I think you want this instead:

```
overlay    chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/addons.xul application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} appversion<3.7
overlay    chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://greasemonkey/content/addonstab.xul application={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384} appversion>=3.7a5pre
```

Comment: Thx for the response, this will certainly be part of the answer in the long run, but I'm still having issues overlaying this new addon manager, see the edit to my question above.